# Find the tangents to the following curve from the given point.

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

2x^2 + y^2 = 54 from (10,1)

P.S. I still don't study calculus. This lesson is from analytic geometry and I have no idea how to solve it because my professor didn't teach it. So if someone could tell me step-by-step on how to do it , I would appreciate it very much.

I really need it later so please don't put the question on hold again. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Let the tangent line have slope $m$. Then the line has equation $y=mx-10m+1$. Substitute for $y$ in $2x^2+y^2=54$. We get a quadratic in $x$. The line is tangent to the ellipse if and only if the quadratic has a double root. This is true precisely if the discriminant "$b^2-4ac$" is $0$. That will give you a quadratic equation in $m$. Solve. That's probably how you are expected to do it. I have a nice alternate way of doing it that I can type if I find out the question has been reopened.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing your alternative method, since this question is open again.

Comment: Have you seen a similar problem? How was that problem solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow through on **André Nicholas**' comment (I'd proposed this approach, but dropped the comment when the question looked like it would get "closed"), the equation for the ellipse becomes

$$ 2X^2 \ + \ (mX + [1 - 10m])^2 \ = \ 54 \ , $$

where $ \ (X,Y) \ = \ (X, mX+[1−10m] ) \ \ $ is the tangent point on the ellipse.  It is *important* in making the computation at this point **not** to multiply everything out (the other reason I dropped my comment, since the actual execution of this approach has to be carried out carefully to avoid insanity, and needs more than a comment to discuss).  The resulting quadratic equation in $ \ X \ $ should best be written

$$  (m^2 + 2) \ X^2 \ + \ 2m \ (1 - 10m) \ X \ + \ [ \ (1-10m)^2 - 54 ] \ = \ 0  , $$

for which the discriminant is

$$ \ D \ = \ 4m^2 \ (1-10m)^2 \ - \ 4  \cdot   (m^2 + 2)  \cdot  [ \ (1-10m)^2 - 54 ] \ \ . $$

In order to have a  tangent point, the line must intersect the ellipse for a single value of $ \ X \ , $ so we want this discriminant to be zero:

$$ 4m^2 \ (1-10m)^2 \ - \ 4  \cdot   (m^2 + 2)  \cdot  [ \ (1-10m)^2 - 54 ] \ = 0   $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ m^2 \ (1-10m)^2 \ = \  (m^2 + 2)  \cdot  [ \ (1-10m)^2 - 54 ]  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 0 \ = \  2  \cdot   (1-10m)^2 \ - \ (m^2 + 2) \cdot 54  $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 146m^2 \ - \ 40m^2 \ - \ 106 \ = 0 \ \ . $$

In this way, we get the quadratic equation to solve for the slopes of the tangent lines, rather than a rather scary *quartic* equation.  Here is a graph of the geometrical arrangement.

[image]

When you reach calculus, you'll learn a much simpler way to deal with this sort of problem (and one applicable to curves more complicated than conic sections).

Comment: Thank you very much! Until this time, I still don't know what a discriminant is, but after getting the positive and negative roots I've been able to get those two equations. Godspeed! :D

Answer (score 0):

Do you know calculus? If yes, note that for $x>0$, the equation of the curve is given by
$$
y = f(x) = \sqrt{54 - 2x^2}.
$$
What does $f'(10)$ tell you?

Comment: I still didn't tackled calculus.